# JAVA Error in Input I/O homework (beginner)

Tags: java, file, io, printwriter

I have to write a program that estimates the number of bottles of a drink someone would have to drink to win a prize, if there is a 1 in 5 chance that a bottle cap will have a prize. The user inputs the number of trials of opening bottles, and the program outputs the average number of bottles taken to win a prize, and stores how many drinks each individual trial took to win, in a separate text file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class BottleCapPrize2
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Number of Trials: ");
   int trials = in.nextInt();
   int trialNumber = 0;
   int total = 0;
   int average = 0;

   for (int x = 0; x < trials; x++){
      int counter = 0;
      double randNum = Math.random();
      trialNumber++;

       while (randNum < 0.8){
       counter ++;
       randNum = Math.random();
       }

     total += counter;
     average = (int) total/trials;
     PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File ("bottleCap.txt"));
     outFile.println("Trial " + trialNumber + " took " + counter + " drinks.");
     outFile.close();

     if (trialNumber == trials){
     System.out.println("The average was " + average);

    }
   }    
 }
```

The part of the program that outputs to the compiler works fine, but the part that outputs to the text file (bottleCap.txt) does not work correctly.

When I open bottleCap.txt, something along the lines of 
"Trial 1 took 3 drinks.", "Trial 2 took 5 drinks.", .... "Trial 10 took 9 drinks." should be written.
Instead, I only see the output for the last Trial of the program. (If the user entered 10 trials, then the text file only has written "Trial 10 took 3 drinks", and nothing for Trials 1-9).

Can someone help me figure out the problem? I have looked at this for a few hours now, and have not gotten any further. Thank You!

**Thank you everyone for your help! This was very helpful! **

Comment: Check your for loop block.

Comment: Move the creation and closing of outFile outside of the loop. A newly opened file starts writing at the start if not specified otherwise. It also takes time to open a file.

Comment: @jinjin11 My question is so your data **overwrites** each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are creating a new  file each time. for each loop you are creating a file and write and then you are creating a new empty file and then write.

so you have to declare the print writer out of the loop

```
 PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File ("bottleCap.txt"));

 for (int x = 0; x < trials; x++){
  int counter = 0;
  double randNum = Math.random();
  trialNumber++;

   while (randNum < 0.8){
   counter ++;
   randNum = Math.random();
   }

 total += counter;
 average = (int) total/trials;
 outFile.println("Trial " + trialNumber + " took " + counter + " drinks.");


 if (trialNumber == trials){
 System.out.println("The average was " + average);

  }
 outFile.close();    
  }
```

Also you shouldnt close the file every time while looping

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `PrintWriter`, use a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) with the `append` flag set to `true`.

```
FileWiter outFile = new FileWriter(new File("bottleCap.txt"), true);
```

Creating the [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)) as you're doing, will truncate the existing file to zero size, so all previous output will be erased. Using the `FileWriter` in append mode will append output to the existing file.

Alternatively, you could move the creation of the `PrintWriter` outside of the loop, thus preventing it from being created multiple times and truncating the file.

Answer (score 0):

Move your open file operation out of the loop , so you only open once to writ in buffered then flush   all string to the file .

```
 PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File ("bottleCap.txt"));
 for (int x = 0; x < trials; x++){
  int counter = 0;
  double randNum = Math.random();
  trialNumber++;

   while (randNum < 0.8){
   counter ++;
   randNum = Math.random();
   }

 total += counter;
 average = (int) total/trials;  
 outFile.println("Trial " + trialNumber + " took " + counter + " drinks.");
 if (trialNumber == trials){
 System.out.println("The average was " + average);

}}
   outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to use chain of  `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter`, and the key point is `FileWriter` will append String to current file when use the one of its constructor that lets appaneding by adding `true` to last paramter like

```
new FileWriter("bottleCap.txt", true)
```

and when we surrounding it with `BufferedWriter` object in order to be more efficient if you are going to write in the file number of time, so it buffers the string in big chunk and write the big chunk into a file and clearly you can save a lot of time for writing into a file

**Note** :It is possible not to use `BuffredWriter` ,but it is advised because of better performance and ability to buffer the big chunk of Strings and write them once

Just change your

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("bottleCap.txt");
```

to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bottleCap.txt", true)));
```

Example:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bottleCap.txt", true)));){
            String data = " This content will append to the end of the file";
            File file =new File("bottleCap.txt");
        out.println(data);
            }catch(IOException e){
        }
```

It is possible to solve this issue without using `BufferedWriter`, yet the performance will be low as I mentioned.

Example:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("bottleCap.txt", true));) {
            String data = " This content will append to the end of the file";
            File file = new File("bottleCap.txt");
            out.println(data);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

**Suggestion**:

1. Move your `PrintWriter` out of the for loop in order to avoid making `bottleCap.txt` file more than once.
2. Move these lines out of the for loop as well

   `total += counter;
   average = (int) total/trials;`